# Codeigniter JSON Php to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter, parsing

I have a problem about Codeigniter Json Parse.There are my Controller file and View file.My controller file is servis.php. I want to send json array  servis.php to javascript file and write as a console.log() Thank you.

```css
public function bilgileri_Aktar(){

  $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

  $data = json_encode($arr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "servis/bilgileri_Aktar";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            console.log("Working");
            var a = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var myArr = JSON.parse(a);
        myFunction(myArr);
          }
        };
          xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
          xmlhttp.send();

          function myFunction(arr) {
             for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
               console.log(arr[i]);
             }
}

  
</script>
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

print the json encoded data and then exit it.

And if you console.log that response string, will show you the response data.

```
print json_encode($arr);
exit;
```

Comment: Omg. You're genius. Thank you.

Comment: But I want to send javascript file. That's only write my json. I want to show with console.log() command

Comment: You can user CSS selectors with jQuery function eg .append() or .text() to update the HTML view.

eg 
jQuery('#innerTxt').text(arr.a);

OR

jQuery('#innerTxt').append(arr.a);